# decorator pattern: value of field of concrete component is the value of field from component, but why?

Tags: java, decorator

I'm playing around with the decorator pattern example of the book "Head First Design Patterns". I thought that the value of the field description of `beverage3` has to be "House Blend Coffee", but it is "Unknown Beverage".

Can somebody explain this? We are coding against interfaces (well, in this example it is an abstract class), but I'm still instantiating the class HouseBlend, so the value should be "House Blend Coffee", but it's not...

The code below doesen't contain all classes of the example.

```
public class StarbuzzCoffee {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Beverage beverage = new Espresso();
    System.out.println(beverage.getDescription()
            + " $" + beverage.cost());

    Beverage beverage2 = new DarkRoast();
    beverage2 = new Mocha(beverage2);
    beverage2 = new Mocha(beverage2);
    beverage2 = new Whip(beverage2);
    System.out.println(beverage2.getDescription()
            + " $" + beverage2.cost());

    Beverage beverage3 = new HouseBlend();
    System.out.println("(added by me)return value of getDescription() without condiment: " + beverage3.getDescription());
    beverage3 = new Soy(beverage3);
    beverage3 = new Mocha(beverage3);
    beverage3 = new Whip(beverage3);
    System.out.println(beverage3.getDescription()
            + " $" + beverage3.cost());

    System.out.println("(added by me)value of field desciption: " + beverage3.description);
    }
}
```

Beverage.java

```
public abstract class Beverage {

    String description = "Unknown Beverage";

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public abstract double cost();
}
```

CondimentDecorator.java

```
public abstract class CondimentDecorator extends Beverage {

    public abstract String getDescription();
}
```

HouseBlend.java

```
public class HouseBlend extends Beverage{

    public HouseBlend() {
        description = "House Blend Coffee";
    }
    @Override
    public double cost() {
        return .89;
    }

}
```

CondimentDecorator.java

```
public class Mocha extends CondimentDecorator{

    Beverage beverage;

    public Mocha(Beverage beverage) {
        this.beverage = beverage;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return beverage.getDescription() + ", Mocha";
    }

    @Override
    public double cost() {
        return beverage.cost() + .20;
    }

}
```

Comment: I've added more explanations in the answer to help you. If you still have doubts, just ask. I've been bitten by this problem before... Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Mocha object you're creating is itself a Beverage that has a description. You were not changing its description. You're passing another beverage and enhancing the description of the decorated object. But, you still have your former description of the Mocha object there. When you access its description directly (that's what you were doing by not using the getDescription method), you're accessing the unchanged field and thus you'll get the "Unknown Beverage" printed.

Every beverage you create will have its field description. If you use it without changing it, you'll get the "Unknown Beverage".

Make the String description of class Beverage protected and only access it through the overrided getDescription method of your implementation of Beverage. Check it out:

```
public class StarbuzzCoffee {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Beverage beverage3 = new HouseBlend();
        System.out
            .println("(added by me)return value of getDescription() without condiment: " + beverage3.getDescription());
        beverage3 = new Mocha(beverage3);
        System.out.println(beverage3.getDescription() + " $" + beverage3.cost());

        System.out.println("(added by me)value of field desciption: " + beverage3.getDescription());
    }
}

abstract class Beverage {

  protected String description = "Unknown Beverage";

  public String getDescription() {
      return description;
  }

  public abstract double cost();
}

abstract class CondimentDecorator extends Beverage {

  public abstract String getDescription();
}

class HouseBlend extends Beverage{

  public HouseBlend() {
    description = "House Blend Coffee";
  }
  @Override
  public double cost() {
      return .89;
  }

}

class Mocha extends CondimentDecorator{

  Beverage beverage;

  public Mocha(Beverage beverage) {
      this.beverage = beverage;
  }

  @Override
  public String getDescription() {
      return beverage.getDescription() + ", Mocha";
  }

  @Override
  public double cost() {
      return beverage.cost() + .20;
  }

}
```

Regarding design, it would be safer to make Beverage's getDescription abstract and force every implementation to override it. That way you'll avoid this kind of problem in the future. Check it out:

```
public class StarbuzzCoffee {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Beverage beverage3 = new HouseBlend();
        System.out
            .println("(added by me)return value of getDescription() without condiment: " + beverage3.getDescription());
        beverage3 = new Mocha(beverage3);
        System.out.println(beverage3.getDescription() + " $" + beverage3.cost());

        System.out.println("(added by me)value of field desciption: " + beverage3.description);
    }

}

abstract class Beverage {

  protected String description = "Unknown Beverage";

  public abstract String getDescription();

  public abstract double cost();
}

abstract class CondimentDecorator extends Beverage {
    // You don't need this code here. Because Beverage already 
    // provides a getDescription
  // public abstract String getDescription();
}

class HouseBlend extends Beverage{

  public HouseBlend() {
    description = "House Blend Coffee";
  }

  @Override
  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }

  @Override
  public double cost() {
      return .89;
  }

}

class Mocha extends CondimentDecorator{
  // Also make sure that this guy here is private
  // so other objects can't change or access 
  // its state without going through Mocha
  private Beverage beverage;

  public Mocha(Beverage beverage) {
      this.beverage = beverage;
  }

  @Override
  public String getDescription() {
      return beverage.getDescription() + ", Mocha";
  }

  @Override
  public double cost() {
      return beverage.cost() + .20;
  }

}
```